# Disable Automatic Registration of JAX-RS Resources on WebLogic 12c / Jersey

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, weblogic, jersey-client

WebLogic 12c includes a Default JAX-RS resource (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/configure.htm#RESTF191) that will register all classes annotated with JAX-RS annotations as resources.

I use the Jersey proxy client (http://blog.alutam.com/2012/05/04/proxy-client-on-top-of-jax-rs-2-0-client-api/), so my interface classes have all the JAX-RS annotations and are packaged in their own "API" jar. The API jar is then deployed to basically two different contexts: the service and the client. The Service provides an implementation of the API that is the actual business logic and is exposed as a JAX-RS web service. The client is just a consumer of the service and the implementations of the service interfaces in the API jar are Jersey Proxy Clients.

Unfortunately, WebLogic 12c is causing me two problems here:

1) It is automatically registering all the resources in my API jars and exposing them as web services from the client application (with the implementation being the (now literally) proxy client)! Which is extremely unintended.

2) Sometimes I want to use classes from an API without actually consuming the service, so I don't even provide implementations for the interfaces. This should be fine, but because WebLogic is attempting to automatically load the API resources, but not finding implementations for the annotated interfaces, it refuses to deploy the war.

I could hack around issue 1 with security policies or weird jax-rs configurations in the web.xml, but that doesn't solve issue 2. The best solution is just to turn off the Default Resource in WebLogic, but I can't find any documentation to do so.

Is there any way to turn off the Default Resource in WebLogic or turn off automatic Jersey scanning?

Comment: Also an issue on 12.2.1.3

Comment: @theBushman Are you using an empty Application subclass for you app configuration?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I can't be certain unfortunately. Not using an empty Application subclass on purpose anyway. The classes being picked up (as in point 1 above) are from a 3rd party jar from another client's pre-compiled code, so I can't change it. It has been suggested to me that deleting some jars from ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules like com.sun.jersey.jersey-core.jar should stop jersey from trying to register at all but this is also not working, causing other ClassNotFoundException issues at deployment time.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, removing these files from weblogic 12.2.1.3 completely removes jersey from starting up and scanning the classpath for annotations:

```
wlserver/modules/weblogic.jaxrs.integration.jar
oracle_common/modules/com.sun.jersey.jersey-core.jar
oracle_common/modules/weblogic.jaxrs.portable.server.jar
```

The weblogic portable server is activated by the [hk2](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/) dependency injection system, which loads jersey as an OSGI bundle and activates it

Comment: This solved it for me on WL12.2.1.3. Thanks @Alftheo.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I'm not yet ready to accept an answer that involves deleting jars from the installation.

Comment: This solved my problem on WebLogic 12.2.1.4. But did you find a way to solve it without deleting?

Comment: No, the deletes are still part of my standard installation script